# How to load large CSV into Python, select specific columns and save as new CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that is about 8 million rows and about 3gb in size. I have a list of specific columns I want to save into a new CSV. I have been trying to use Panda with Python but I just can not get it right.

This is the code I have been using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('MyFile.csv' , usecols = ['AAA','BBB','CCC',])
```

After the last command the terminal line returns 3 dots like this "...". Then I try to enter this command

```
df.to_csv('NewFile.csv', index=False)
```

But I receive the following error:

```
file "<stdin>", line 2
  df.to_csv('NewFile.csv', index=False)
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help would be so greatly appreciated it. Thank you.

EDIT: This is what the entire terminal screen text is.

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> df=pd.read_csv('MyFile.csv' , usecols = ['AAA','BBB','CCC',]
... pd.df.to_csv('NewFile.csv', index=False)?
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    pd.df.to_csv('NewFile.csv', index=False)?
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: Could you please share full code listing? You received _SyntaxError_ and it's not clear why. Having a full code could help reveal it

Comment: I am not 100% sure how I do that. I am very new to Python. The lines from the original post is a copy paste of what I put in, but I did just edit my post to include all the text from Anaconda Powershell Prompt from when I typed "Python". Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Reading a 3GB file into memory is not a good idea (and that is what pandas will do). I would suggest using a streaming tool like `awk` to filter your data first.

Comment: I thought that could be an issue. I have to work this file three times a year and every time it such a pain. I will have to looking into awk filter...

Comment: And maybe I should say the file is 2.6Gb, not sure if it really matters but I should have been more defined.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\NewFile.csv', index = False)
```

Replace `C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\NewFile.csv` with the output file name.

Comment: I just tried it and get the same syntax error message but the carrot arrow appears under the "d" in "pd".

Answer (score 1):

You got syntax error because you haven't closed the bracket in below line in terminal

```
>>> df=pd.read_csv('MyFile.csv' , usecols = ['AAA','BBB','CCC',]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. I find a code to just delete the columns I did not want. So copied the CSV and did that. This is the Py file I used:

```
import csv

input_file = 'input.csv'
output_file = 'output.csv'
cols_to_remove = [1, 4, 10, 11] # Column indexes to be removed (starts at 0)

cols_to_remove = sorted(cols_to_remove, reverse=True) # Reverse so we remove from              the end first
row_count = 0 # Current amount of rows processed

with open(input_file, "r") as source:
reader = csv.reader(source)
with open(output_file, "w", newline='') as result:
    writer = csv.writer(result)
    for row in reader:
        row_count += 1
        print('\r{0}'.format(row_count), end='') # Print rows processed
        for col_index in cols_to_remove:
            del row[col_index]
        writer.writerow(row)
```